# Creating custom PropTypes that extend default PropTypes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom PropType that checks if an array has numerical values and has a length of 2  (and there's some constraint on the ordering of the numbers).

Obviously I can do `Array.PropType.arrayOf(Array.PropType.number)` for the first two constraints.

I'd like to reuse this in my custom PropType (instead of rolling out my own numerical and array check).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.PropTypes.arrayOf( React.PropTypes.number )` just returns a function, so you can instead provide your own function to perform the validation.

Your function will be passed three parameters: `props, propName, componentName`

see the second to last example shown in [React.PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes) from the docs.

So a function that should satisfy your constraints would be:

```
function isTwoElementArrayOfNumbers( props, propName, componentName ){
  var _array = props[ propName ];

  if( _array && _array.constructor === Array && _array.length === 2 ){

    if( !_array.every(
      function isNumber( element ){
        return typeof element === 'number';
      })
    ){

      return new Error('elements must be numbers!');
    }
  }
  else{
    return new Error('2 element array of numbers not provided!');
  }
}

...in your react element
propTypes:{
  numArray: isTwoElementArrayOfNumbers
},
```

Comment: Attempting to do this fires a warning in React 15.3.x: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: @ConAntonakos: to be more specific, in React 15, the first solution in my answer (reusing `PropType`'s `arrayOf`) became problematic. My actual suggested solution (writing your own simple function to check the prop) is perfectly valid and still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about extending them, I'm not sure that's possible.

But you could store the above as an exported constant and use it to compose properties of other propTypes (but I think you probably already know this):

```
export const CustomProp = Array.PropType.arrayOf(Array.PropType.number)

export const OtherCustomProp = contains({
 foo: React.PropTypes.string,
 bars: CustomProp
});
```